# Is ibn Abbas statement and statement of Hasan Al basri authentic

Tags: hadith, reference-request

On tafsir of verse of [quran 4:34](https://legacy.quran.com/4/34) and [Muslim, 1218](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1218a).
‘Ata said: I said to Ibn `Abbas, what is the kind of hitting that is not harsh? He said, Hitting with a siwak and the like"
And
Al-Hasan al-Basri said: “This means that it should not cause pain.”
Are these hadith authentically attributed to them.
Can you please provide a reference that is authentic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of such a report is clear it comes from a tafsir like tafsir at-Tabari.

**Sources of the report of ibn 'Abbas's explanation**

So imam at-Tabari when explaining the part:

> ...strike them...

from the verse [4:34](https://legacy.quran.com/4/34) mentioned several reports that say don't hit them harsh among them is the one you've mentioned, here's the full quote as is in his tafsir (see [here](https://shamela.ws/book/43/4398#p1) and the following page):
<sup>In the following I'm translating from Arabic language as these translations are of my own take them carefully!</sup>

> ٩٣٨٦ - حدثنا المثنى قال، حدثنا إسحاق قال، حدثنا ابن عيينة، عن ابن جريج، عن عطاء قال: قلت لابن عباس: ما الضرب غير المبرح؟ قال: السواك وشبهه، يضربها به.
> 9386 -  Al-Muthanna informed us from Ishaaq from ibn 'Uyaynah from ibn Jaraij from  'Ata who said: I said to Ibn 'Abbas, what is the kind of hitting that is not harsh? He said, "Hitting with a siwak and the like"
> ٩٣٨٧ - حدثنا إبراهيم بن سعيد الجوهري قال، حدثنا ابن عيينة، عن ابن جريج، عن عطاء قال، قلت لابن عباس: ما الضرب غير المبرح؟ قال: بالسواك ونحوه.
> 9387 - Ibrahim ibn Sa'id al-Jawhari infromed us from ibn 'Uyaynah from ibn Juraij from 'ata who said I said to ibn 'Abbas, what is the kind of hitting thatis not harsh? He said, "hitting with a siwak and alike"

Both of the above chains are connected and have narrators of a high trust level therefore it is safe to say that these reports are sahih.

He also added a third report with the same meaning(same source see [here](https://shamela.ws/book/43/4399#p1)):

> ٩٣٨٨ - حدثنا المثنى قال، حدثنا حبان بن موسى قال، أخبرنا ابن المبارك قال، أخبرنا ابن عيينة، عن ابن جريج، عن عطاء قال: قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم في خطبته:"ضربا غير مبرح"، قال: السواك ونحوه.
> 9388 - Al-Muthanna informed us from Hibban ibn Musa from ibn al-Mubarak from ibn 'Uyaynah from ibn Juraij from 'Ata' who said: The messenger of Allah Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him said in his sermon: "A hitting that is not harsh", he said: Siwak and alike

This report is referring to a part of the sermon at the farewell hajj (hajjatu al-Wada') which can be found in several sources like in [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1851) and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1163) etc.. Of course this hadith report is mursal (its disconnected) as 'Ata' is not a sahabi.

See [here hadith #5275 (٥٢٧٥)](https://shamela.ws/book/8658/934#p1) also in the tasfir of abu Hathim ar-Razi where this was reported via Muhammad ibn Isma'il al-Ahmasi محمد بن إسماعيل الأحمسي (trustworthy and a student of Sufyan ibn 'Uyaynah), from Muhammad ibn as-Silt محمد بن الصلت  (trustworthy), from سفيان بن عيينة ibn 'Uyaynah ...

**Sources of the report of al-Hassan al-Basri**

Again at-Tabari mentioned your quoted report in the same context as above, buit a few pages later. Here the full quote (Source see [here](https://shamela.ws/book/43/4400#p1)):

> ٩٣٩٥ - حدثني المثنى قال، حدثنا حبان قال، حدثنا ابن المبارك قال، أخبرنا عبد الوارث بن سعيد، عن رجل، عن الحسن قال: ضربا غير مبرح، غير مؤثر.
> Al-Muthana informed me from Hibban from ibn al-Mubarak from 'abd al-Warith ibn Sa'id from a man from al-Hassan who said: a hitting that is not harsh, not leaving traces <sup>(also possible meaning: not force full or not pain full)</sup>.

This report certainly has issues as we have an unknown narrator between al-Hassan (al-Basri) and 'abd al-Warith ibn Sa'id (عبد الوارث بن سعيد). Nevertheless it shows that 'abd al-Warith's honesty as he was a student of al-Hassan al-Basri he could have said that he heard his master himself, but he didn't and unfortunately he didn't know the person who reported his masters words.

Ibn abi Hatim ar-Razi also reported this in his tafsir (see [here](https://shamela.ws/book/8658/934#p1)) -the translation of "غير المؤثر" here is based on the quote from OP's question, I've already mentioned possible other translations in the quote above-:

> ٥٢٧٤ - حدثنا أبي، ثنا أبو سلمة قال: قال حماد: فقلت لحميد: المبرح؟ قال حميد: فقلت للحسن: ما المبرح؟ قال: غير المؤثر.
> 5274 - My father informed me from abu Salamah from Hammad who said: I asked Humaid  <sup>(at-Taweel)</sup>: not harsh? Humaid said: I then said to al-Hassan: What does not harsh mean? He said: which doesn't cause pain.

Comment: Above first narration are from ibn uyaynah who was mudallis and he is saying "an" ibn jurayj       how is it sahih?

Comment: @Subhan just because somebody is a mudallis doesn't mean he's not trustworthy. Ibn 'Uyynah in fact has a high level of trust if we are careful about the cases where he performed tadlees and exclude those. It must further be noted that ibn 'Uyynah doesn't hide a weak narrator with his tadlees since he only performed it on trustworthy people like ibn Juraij and Ma'amar. As a matter of fact many earlier scholars would fall in the category of mudallis. So one must have a good picture of ibn 'Uyynah and the narratives in which he usually performed tadlees.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - In the first narration, who is this narrator "Muthanna"? Thanks.